# Laravel 5.3 get custom Array (Object) from Eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have Products, Attributes and Categories. I want to create custom attributes array without using foreach. I know I can get that done with foreach but I want to do it with Eloquent query.

This is my table diagram:
[image: Attributes tables diagram]

I want to create array (Eloquent returned Object) like this:

```
$attributes = [
        'attribute1' => [
            'attribute1_property1' => 'attribute1_property1_count_in_all_products',
            'attribute1_property2' => 'attribute1_property2_count_in_all_products',
            'attribute1_property3' => 'attribute1_property3_count_in_all_products',
        ],
        'attribute2' => [
            'attribute2_property1' => 'attribute1_property1_count_in_all_products',
            'attribute2_property2' => 'attribute1_property2_count_in_all_products',
            'attribute2_property3' => 'attribute1_property3_count_in_all_products',
        ],
        ...
    ]
```

I have models `Product`, `Attribute`, `AttributeProperty`.

```
Product::whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($catId) {
        $q->whereId($catId);
    })->with('attributeProperties.attribute')->get();
```

With above code I get list of products and it's attribute options but I want that attribute options grouped by parent attribute and counted how many products had that attribute option.

In other words I want to get all `attribute_options` grouped by parent `attribute` and counted how many products do that `attribute_option` have on this `category`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Call `toArray()` on the sub collection?

Comment: No That's not the case. I want to get array hirarchy like that in above code.

Comment: For `AttributeOption` I'm not seeing `attribute_options` in the schema?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question it was `AttributeProperty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific reason you are querying the `Product` model?  If that's not needed and you're just after the example array you can do it like:

```
$results = Attribute::with(['attributeProperties' => function($query) {
    return $query->withCount('products');
}])->get();
```

You can access what you want through the collections (I'm taking the first item of each just for reference):

```
$attribute = $results->first();
$attributeProperty = $attribute->attributeProperties->first();
$attributeProperty->products_count;
```

**OR** if you need it in that EXACT format you can map the results like:

```
$results->keyBy('display_name')->map(function($attribute) {
    return $attribute->attributeProperties
        ->keyBy('display_name')
        ->map(function($property) {
            return $poperty->products_count;
        })
        ->toArray();
})
->toArray();
```